# Error 400: invalid_request The out-of-band (OOB) flow has been blocked in order to keep users secure

Tags: python, android, api, google-cloud-platform, android-management-api

> using this quickstart.ipynb
> I'm getting this error
> You can’t sign in because "myapp" sent an invalid request. You can try again later, or contact the developer about this issue. Learn more about this error
> If you are a developer of myapp, see error details.
> Error 400: invalid_request

> Error 400: invalid_request
> The out-of-band (OOB) flow has been blocked in order to keep users secure. Follow the Out-of-Band (OOB) flow Migration Guide linked in the developer docs below to migrate your app to an alternative method.
> Request details: redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob

> This is the code which is running

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

CLIENT_CONFIG = {
'installed': {
'client_id':'----------------------------------------------------------',
'client_secret': '------------------------------------------------------',
'auth_uri':'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
'token_uri':'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token'
}
}
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidmanagement']

flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_config(CLIENT_CONFIG, SCOPES)
credentials = flow.run_console()

androidmanagement = build('androidmanagement', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

print('\nAuthentication succeeded.')
```

Comment: I have a similar issue, were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Google has deprecated OOB

You have to use the new method **run_local_server()** if you are using the **google_auth_oauthlib** package

Replace the line

```
credentials = flow.run_console()
```

to

```
credentials = flow.run_local_server()
```

Answer (score 0):

The out-of-band (OOB) flow has been blocked.

**Use the below code** Replace your 'your client id' and 'your client secret'

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import Flow

# This is a public OAuth config that you can use to run this guide.
# However, use different credentials when building your own solution.
CLIENT_CONFIG = {
  'web': {
    'client_id':'your client id',
    'auth_uri':'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
    'token_uri':'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
'auth_provider_x509_cert_url':'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs',
'client_secret':'your client secret'
  }
}
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidmanagement']
CALLBACK_URL = 'https://google.github.io/android-management-api-    samples/oauth_callback.html'

# Run the OAuth flow.
flow = Flow.from_client_config(CLIENT_CONFIG, SCOPES)
flow.redirect_uri = CALLBACK_URL
auth_url, _ = flow.authorization_url()
print('Please visit this URL to authorize this application:     {}'.format(auth_url))

code = input('Enter the authorization code: ')
flow.fetch_token(code=code)

# Create the API client.
androidmanagement = build('androidmanagement', 'v1',     credentials=flow.credentials)

print('\nAuthentication succeeded.')
```

full link for Android Management API Quick Start https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/android-management-api-samples/blob/master/notebooks/quickstart.ipynb